# Is it possible to run appium test on real ios device in windows

Tags: ios, windows, appium

I m working on mobile automation and Android automation using Emulator and finding the UI elements does not seem a problem with the windows machine. Now I have to do the same thing for iOS, Can I proceed in Windows or should I get a Mac to work on iOS?

P.S : The programming language I am working on is Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. For iOS app automation, you would need XCode which doesn't work on Windows. So you need to use a Mac.

Also, Mac works with both Android and iOS apps.

Comment: so not only to create the script but to execute also I need a Mac, or Can I just use it to create and later execute it in a windows machine. ?TIA

Comment: Execution also needs Mac. iOS app would not get launched when you run it on Windows.